# Embedded Youtube Block Thumbnail

Tags: files

I seem to be having an issue with the auto generated Thumbnail of a you tube video that shows in a block as a teaser on my frontpage.

When viewing the front page using Firefox the thumbnails are shown. But when viewing on IE11 I just get the alternative text description without the thumbnail.

I am using Drupal 7

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `/watch?v= parameter` (i.e. `www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9eXzmVzDR8`) instead of `www.youtube.com/embed/Y9eXzmVzDR8` when adding content to the field.